# Dirichlet's integral $\int_{V}\ x^{p}\,y^{q}\,z^{r}\ \left(\, 1 - x - y - z\,\right)^{\,s}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I found such an exercise:

Calculate the Dirichlet's integral:

$$
\int_{V}\ x^{p}\,y^{q}\,z^{r}\
\left(\, 1 - x - y - z\,\right)^{\,s}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z
\quad\mbox{where}\quad p, q, r, s >0
$$
and $V=\left\{\,\left(\, x,y,z\,\right) \in {\mathbb R}^{3}_{+}:
x + y + z\ \leq\ 1\right\}$

I thought that I could put $x + y + z = \alpha$. I got a clue, that it is a correct approach, but I should also put $y + z = \alpha\beta$ and $z=\alpha\beta\gamma$. So:

$z=\alpha\beta\gamma\,,\quad y=\alpha\beta\left(\, 1 - \gamma\,\right)\,,\quad x=\alpha\left(\, 1 - \beta\,\right)$

Should I change $x,y,z$ under the integral sign to $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ now ?.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Type I [Dirichlet integrals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletIntegrals.html), one has the formula:

$$\int_{\Delta_n} f\left(\sum_{k=1}^n t_k\right) \prod_{k=1}^n t_k^{\alpha_k-1}\prod_{k=1}^n dt_k = \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n \Gamma(\alpha_k)}{\Gamma(\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k)}\int_0^1
f(\tau) \tau^{(\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k)-1} d\tau$$

where $$\Delta_n = \bigg\{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in [0,\infty)^n :  \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \le 1 \bigg\}$$
is the standard $n$-simplex. For a proof of a very similar formula where $\Delta_n$ is replaced by $[0,\infty)^n$, see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/985215/59379).
It will show you how to carry out the computation in your original approach.

Apply it to your integral with

$$f(w) = (1-w)^s\quad\text{ and }\quad
\begin{cases}
\alpha_1 = p + 1\\
\alpha_2 = q + 1\\
\alpha_3 = r + 1
\end{cases},
$$
one find

$$\begin{align}
  \int_{\Delta_3}(1-x-y-z)^s x^p y^q z^r dxdydz
= & \frac{\Gamma(p+1)\Gamma(q+1)\Gamma(r+1)}{\Gamma(p+q+r+3)}\int_0^1 (1-\tau)^s t^{p+q+r+2} d\tau\\
= &\frac{\Gamma(p+1)\Gamma(q+1)\Gamma(r+1)\Gamma(s+1)}{\Gamma(p+q+r+s+4)}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 7):

Why not to map $(x,y,z)$ into $(u^2,v^2,w^2)$ and integrate over a spherical sector?

With the first change of variables we have:
$$ I = 8\iiint_S u^{2p+1} v^{2q+1} w^{2r+1} (1-(u^2+v^2+w^2))^s\,d\mu $$
where $S=\{(u,v,w)\in(0,+\infty)^3: u^2+v^2+w^2\leq 1\}$.

By setting $u=\rho\cos\theta\sin\phi, v=\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi, w=\rho\cos\phi$, we get:

$$ I = 8\int_{0}^{1}\iint_{(0,\pi/2)^2}\rho^{2p+2q+2r+5}(1-\rho^2)^s\cos^{2p+1}\theta\sin^{2q+1}\theta\cos^{2r+1}\phi\sin^{2p+2q+3}\phi\,d\mu\,d\rho,$$
but since, due to the properties of the [Euler Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function):
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\rho^{2p+2q+2r+5}(1-\rho^2)^s\,d\rho = \frac{\Gamma(3+p+q+r)\Gamma(1+s)}{2\Gamma(4+p+q+r+s)},$$
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2p+1}\theta\sin^{2q+1}\theta\,d\theta = \frac{\Gamma(p+1)\Gamma(q+1)}{2\Gamma(2+p+q)},$$
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2r+1}\phi\sin^{2p+2q+3}\phi\,d\phi=\frac{\Gamma(2+p+q)\Gamma(1+r)}{2\Gamma(3+p+q+r)},$$
it follows that:
$$ \color{red}{I=\frac{\Gamma(p+1)\Gamma(q+1)\Gamma(r+1)\Gamma(s+1)}{\Gamma(4+p+q+r+s)}}. $$

Comment: Well, thanks. My first question is what do you mean by $d\mu$? Do you mean $d\mu(u,v,w)$? And my second question is there an alternative solution using the change I wrote above or this one is just simpler?

Comment: @Novsar: yes, $d\mu$ is a shortcut notation for $du\,dv\,dw$ in the first case and for $d\theta\,d\phi$ in the second case. I haven't tried your change of variables since this one looked to me as the most natural way for separating variables and "factor" the integral, but probably your way is as efficient as mine.

Comment: @Novsar: Ok, the achille hui's answer confirms the feeling.

Comment: Why is there $2$ in the denomiantor of last 3 integrals? Could you explain me this?

Comment: @Novsar: it is due to some change of variable bringing such integrals in the usual form, suited for beta-function evaluation. For instance: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^\alpha(\theta)\,d\theta = \int_{0}^{1} t^{\alpha}(1-t^2)^{-1/2}\,dt = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{1}u^{(\alpha-1)/2}(1-u)^{-1/2}\,du.$$

Comment: I've just found out why. Thank you a lot for help. I really liked your solution to the problem. :)

Comment: Miraculuous! I was not expecting such a nice result.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{V}\ x^{p}\,y^{q}\,z^{r}\
\pars{1 - x - y - z}^{\,s}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z\,;\
p, q, r, s >0}$ and $\ds{V=\braces{\pars{ x,y,z} \in {\mathbb R}^{3}_{+}:
x + y + z\ \leq\ 1}}$

---

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\left.
\int_{V}\ x^{p}\,y^{q}\,z^{r}\pars{1 - x - y - z}^{\, s}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z\,
\right\vert_{\, x + y + z\ < 1}}
\\[5mm]&=\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{p}\,y^{q}\,z^{r}
\pars{1 - x - y - z}^{\,s}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z\,
\right\vert_{\, x + y + z\ < 1}
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{p}\,y^{q}\,z^{r}\
\Theta\pars{1 - x - y - z}\pars{1 - x - y - z}^{\,s}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{p}\,y^{q}\,z^{r}\ \overbrace{\int_{0^{-}}^{\infty}
\delta\pars{1 - x - y - z - \xi}\xi^{\,s}\,\dd\xi}
^{\dsc{\Theta\pars{1 - x - y - z}\pars{1 - x - y - z}^{\,s}}}\
\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0^{-}}^{\infty}x^{p}\,y^{q}\,z^{r}\xi^{\,s}\ \overbrace{%
\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}
\exp\pars{\tau\bracks{1 - x - y - z - \xi}}\,{\dd\tau \over 2\pi\ic}}
^{\dsc{\delta\pars{1 - x - y - z - \xi}}}\,\,\,\,
\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z\,\dd\xi
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}\expo{\tau}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{p}\expo{-\tau x}\,\dd x}
^{\dsc{\tau^{-p - 1}\ \Gamma\pars{p + 1}}}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{q}\expo{-\tau y}\,\dd y}
_{\dsc{\tau^{-q - 1}\ \Gamma\pars{q + 1}}}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}z^{r}\expo{-\tau z}\,\dd z}
^{\dsc{\tau^{-r - 1}\ \Gamma\pars{r + 1}}}\times \\[2mm] &
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\xi^{s}\expo{-\tau\xi}\,\dd\xi}
_{\dsc{\tau^{-s - 1}\ \Gamma\pars{s + 1}}}\,\,\,\,
\,{\dd\tau \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\Gamma\pars{p + 1}\Gamma\pars{q + 1}\Gamma\pars{r + 1}\Gamma\pars{s + 1}\times \\[2mm] &
\underbrace{\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}
\frac{\expo{\tau}}{\tau^{p + q + r + s + 4}}\,\,\,{\dd\tau \over 2\pi\ic}}
_{\ds{\dsc{1 \over \pars{p + q + r + s + 3}!}\ =\
      \dsc{1 \over \Gamma\pars{p + q + r + s + 4}}}}
\end{align}

---

Finally,
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\left.%
\int_{V}\ x^{p}\,y^{q}\,z^{r}\pars{1 - x - y - z}^{\,s}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\,\right\vert_{\, x + y + z\ <\ 1}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{\Gamma\pars{p + 1}\Gamma\pars{q + 1}\Gamma\pars{r + 1}\Gamma\pars{s + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{p + q + r + s + 4}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The answer and more is also given in Handbook of Applicable Mathematics, Vol IV : Analysis, § 10.2 Special functions, (ISBN 04712770405 or 0471101499, 1982, John Wiley and Sons, Ltd, ed. by Walter Ledermann and Steven Vajda). With n > o the gamma function
$$\Gamma(n)= \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\cdot x^{(n-1)}\,dx$$
and after integrating by parts: $\Gamma(n)=(−1)!\quad$
Thus the gamma function is a generalization of the factorial function to the case where n may take non-integral values. For m, n > 0 the beta function
$$\beta(m,n)= \int_0^1x^{m-1}\cdot(1-x)^{(n-1)}\,dx$$

Usually their relation is in the form of (10.2.8 in this book):
$$\beta(m,n)=\frac{\Gamma(m)\cdot\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}$$
Now consider the integral
$$\iiint x^p  y^q z^r (1-x-y-z)^s\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
taken throughout the interior of the tetrahedron formed bij the planes $x = 0,\; y = 0, \; z = 0, \; x + y + z = 1$. Define new variables $\alpha = x + y + z, \quad \beta = y + z, \quad \gamma =z\quad$ or equivalently
$x = \alpha(1-\beta),\quad y=\alpha\beta(1-\gamma),\quad z = \alpha\beta\gamma \,$. When x, y, z are all positive and x + y + z < 1,
$\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ all lie between 0 and 1. Hence the tetrahedron transforms into a cube. The Jacobian matrix for this transformation to be inserted [see (5.10.3) and Theorem 6.2.5 in the book]
$$\frac{d(x,y,z)}{d(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)}=\alpha^2\beta$$
Substituting:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1 \alpha^{(p+q+r)} \cdot\beta^{(q+r)} \cdot(1-β)^p \cdot \gamma^r (1-\gamma)^q (1-\alpha)^s \cdot (\alpha^2β)\,d\alpha \,d\beta\,d\gamma)$$ =
$$\left[\int_0^1 \alpha^{(p+q+r+2)}(1-\alpha)^s\,d\alpha\right]\left[\int_0^1 \beta^{(q+r+2)} (1-\beta)^p\,d\beta\right]\left[\int_0^1 \gamma^r (1-\gamma)^q\,d\gamma\right]$$ =
$$\beta(p+q+r+3,s+1)\cdot\beta(q+r+2,p+1)\cdot\beta(r+1,q+1)$$ And by ref. (10.2.8):
$$\frac{\Gamma(p+q+r+3)\Gamma(s+1)Γ(q+r+2)\Gamma(p+1)\Gamma(r+1)\Gamma(q+1)}{\Gamma(p+q+r+4)\Gamma(p+q+r+3)Γ(q+r+2)}$$ = $$\frac{\Gamma(p+1)\Gamma(q+1)\Gamma(r+1)\Gamma(s+1)}{\Gamma(p+q+r+4)}$$
This result, due to Dirichlet, can easily be extended to the case of n variables. In general, the integral which can be evaluated over the same region by a similar method with $f$ any continuous function, is:
$$\iiint x^py^q z^r f(x+y+z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$